# What's the difference among vector<int>() vs vector<int>{} vs NULL vs size=0?

Tags: c++, vector

I want to return an empty vector at the end of my function.
Does the following all equivalent? How to understand each of them?

```
return vector<int>();
return vector<int>{};
return NULL;
```

The following is my understanding:

1.`vector<int>()` means creating an empty vector object, which is uninitialized so it's NULL.

2.`vector<int>{}` means creating an empty vector, which has a size 0.

Is there a difference between size 0 and NULL?
Thanks a lot~

Comment: `NULL` has nothing to do at all with `std::vector`. What type is your function returning?

Comment: `vector<int>()`is not unitiliazed. You call default constructor here. And C++ is not Java, you can't `return NULL` in place of any object.

Comment: Depending on your implementation, trying to return `NULL` in place of a vector *may* find `explicit std::vector::vector(std::size_t)`

Comment: @François Andrieux, the return type is vector<int>

Comment: @LushaLi Then `return NULL;` shouldn't compile. Unlike some other languages, objects in c++ don't implicitly support a null state.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, thanks, I don't know C++ cannot return NULL since I have never tried.  Do you mean we cannot explicitly return NULL but we can return vector<int>(), which is not initialized(vector<int>()=NULL)

Comment: @François Andrieux, thanks.  When return NULL will work? I did some search.  It said it should never work for C++.  If you really want to, we can return a nullptr.

Comment: `vector<int>()` is initialized and is fully functional object. It just doesn't contain any `int`s inside. If you want to learn C++, start with [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). It will be easier than trying to apply your experience from different languages :)

Comment: @LushaLi `NULL` and `nullptr` will work for any function that has a pointer return type. I don't know where you saw that `NULL` never works, that's not true. Maybe you read that it shouldn't be used anymore, since `nullptr` does a better job. Neither will work with `std::vector` return types.

Comment: @François Andrieux, thanks.  I got it.  My bad. It said they would never work for returning references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first two are both doing [*value initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), and are the same.

`NULL` is the old backward-compatible symbolic constant for null *pointers*. C++ doesn't have the concept of "null" values. Unless you return a pointer, it's invalid.

---

Regarding `NULL`, in C++ before the C++11 standard you should really be using `0` for null pointers. And since the C++11 standard you should be using the [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) literal.

Comment: the bracket syntax has the advantage of not having to worry about [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: But braces and parentheses are both types of brackets. You mean the brace syntax, right?

Comment: @Useless by bracket i meant braces

Comment: @Tyker In this specific case there's no ambiguity.

Comment: Do you mean there's no difference between braces and brackets here?

Comment: @LushaLi None at all.